# Get morning Hours And Night Hours between CheckIn Datetime and CheckOut Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

### Info:

- Morning Hours Form 7:00 AM to 7:00 PM
- Night Hours From 7:00 PM to 7:00 AM

### Sample Data:

- Check In: 29-1-2014 7:00 PM Check Out 30-1-2014 3:00 AM  Solution: Morning 0 hours - Night 8 hours
- Check In: 29-1-2014 7:00 PM Check Out 30-1-2014 10:00 AM Solution: Morning 3 hours - Night 12 hours
- Check In: 29-1-2014 5:00 PM Check Out 29-1-2014 11:00 PM Solution: Morning 0 hours - Night 7 hours
- Check In: 29-1-2014 6:00 AM Check Out 29-1-2014 9:00 PM Solution: Morning 12 hours - Night 4 hours

### Problem:

I need to Get morning Hours And Night Hours between CheckIn Datetime and CheckOut Datetime using sql server function.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and code you've used to try to solve the problem.

Comment: If you use a function for this I would recommend an iTVF instead of a scalar function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not following how your solutions correspond to your sample data